# How to get projects to reference correct version of dependency? Specifically EF 5 & 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll

I have a single web project referencing two class libraries.

One of these libraries references `Entity Framework 5.0` and the other references `Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth` which in turn references `Entity Framework 6.0`.

When executing code within the web project which goes on to execute code in the `EF5` library, it complains with:

> Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(System.Data.EntityState)'

I believe this is due to `EF6` being referenced instead of `EF5` and subsequently not finding the above method.

Is my assumption correct? If so, is there a way to get each project to use the correct version without being 'overridden'?

I've looked into binding redirects but not sure how to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the issue by redirecting each library to the correct file.

Here is what you can do:

1. Ensure that the v6 of `EntityFramework` is named `EntityFramework.dll`. Leave it alone;
2. Rename the v5 of `EntityFramework` to `EntityFramework.v5.dll`;
3. If your EF v5 is the version targeting .NET 4.0, you will replace `5.0.0.0` below with `4.4.0.0`;
4. Set up assembly binding in your configuration file with the following parameters:

   ```xml
   <configuration>
     <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
           <codeBase version="5.0.0.0" href="EntityFramework.v5.dll" />
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
   </configuration>
   ```

In that way, each library will get its preferred version of Entity Framework.

However, you should know that there is one big issue with that "solution": if someone counted on Entity Framework being in a single version, you will get issues due to the fact that you really have two versions of Entity Framework loaded in the same application, and you must take care that the application is aware of it (e.g. you may need to configure Entity Framework twice). While it is not the end of the world, it is uncommon enough for .NET libraries in two different version, that virtually no non-MS software expects it.

Really, it should be a lot simpler, and more reliable in the long term, to upgrade the library that uses v5 to use Entity Framework v6.

Comment: Great thanks, I'm just looking into upgrading the EF5 reference actually. If it's not too much bother I'll probably prefer that route.

Comment: @AdamNaylor: Upgrading from EF5 to EF6 should be pretty straightforward, and is explained at length in [Upgrading to EF6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6) on MSDN.